# Object says it is nil when in fact it is not.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, null

this is a very weird thing and probably there is an easy solution but I have no idea whats going on.

This is my method:

```
    def to_event_format
       event = {title: self.client.nombre_completo, start: self.fecha, end: self.fecha.one_hour}
       event
    end
```

The problem is

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `one_hour' for nil:NilClass):
```

The problem is with the self.fecha **.one_hour**

But its not the method what is wrong. I get the same error for methods like .sunday? and other default Time methods.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `sunday?' for nil:NilClass):
```

It gets weirder in the debugger, where the method actually works.

```
(byebug) self.fecha
-> Thu, 30 Oct 2014 19:00:00 UTC +00:00
(byebug) self.fecha.one_hour
-> Thu, 30 Oct 2014 20:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

How can the method work in the debugger but not in the app? And why is it nil when I call a method on it, but works fine when left alone?

I don't understand anything.

Comment: where does `to_event_format` reside? where have you placed `byebug`?

Comment: Are you trying to call this method from a loop? Then for any object of the loop creates that issue.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I did a reset on the database and it started working again. Whats up with that? I guess we will never know.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `end` as the name of one of your keys. Being a reserved word, that's probably causing some problems.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I did a reset on the database and it started working again. Whats up with that? I guess we will never know.